# Xcode Build not submitting due to missing icons

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I've tried numerous times to upload my build for TestFlight but based on the below I cannot seem to get this resolved.

Does anybody have any advice?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: You don't need the Icon Files entry in Info.plist. Setup your app to use your AppIcons assets.

Comment: Thank you - @maddy

I deleted the icon entries but it is still throwing those same errors.  Is there anywhere in the plist I can specify the AppIcon portion?